# Different ways to place the workers on Santorini board game

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving, puzzle

This combinatorics problem is based on the board game [Santorini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santorini_(game)).

Consider a $5 \times 5$ chess board (but all squares are equal, say they're all white).

Player A places $2$ (equal) white workers in $2$ of the $25$ squares.

Player B then places $2$ (equal) black workers in $2$ of the remaining $23$ squares.

> How many different ways can the players place their workers (including **rotations and reflections**)

If we exclude rotations and reflections, then the number is $\binom{25}{2}\times\binom{23}{2} = 75 900$.

But if we consider them this seems a lot more complicated... Is there an easy way to think about this?

What I mean by considering rotations and reflections is that the following configurations should be treated as the same:

"original configuration"

[image]

rotate $90$ degrees clockwise

[image]

rotate $180$ degrees

[image]

vertical axis reflection

[image]

diagonal axis reflection

[image]

**Edit:** **If anyone who knows Burnside's Lemma could confirm my answer, I would appreciate it.**

Comment: What would be an example of a rotation? Rotation of the grid?

Comment: What I wanted to say is that two configurations are equal if you can get one from another by doing a rotation or/and a reflection.

Comment: When counting things up to rotation and reflection, you'll want to use [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), which will have you consider how many configurations stay the same if they're, say, rotated 180°.

Comment: @Babado but then if we have two equal pieces in position $A2$ and $B1$, it will be equal to the configuration where we have pieces in position $D5$ and $E4$? So these two configurations will count as one?

Comment: Yes, that is the same because you can rotate the board

Comment: If you rotate the board 180° clockwise then A2 goes to E4 and B1 goes to D5

Answer (score 1):

As said in one of the comments, using Burnside's lemma could be the way to go.

I've never used it before so this might not be completely correct. **Please let me know if you find any mistake as I'm not completely sure of this answer.**

Let $X$ be the set of $\binom{25}{2}\binom{23}{2}=75900 \ $ possible placements that can be done in one particular orientation.

Let $G$ be the rotation group on $X$.

$G$ has $8$ elements:

- the identity
- two $90^{\circ}$  edge rotations
- one $180^{\circ}$ edge rotation
- four reflections (we can see this as flipping the board $180^{\circ}$): two diagonal, one vertical and one horizontal

The solution of the problem can be found by counting the sizes of the fixed sets for the $8$ elements of $G$:

- the identity leaves all $75900$ elements of $X$ unchanged
- the two $90^{\circ}$ edge rotations leave $0$ elements of $X$ unchanged
- the $180^{\circ}$ edge rotation leaves $\binom{12}{2}\times 2 = 132$ elements of $X$ unchanged
- the four reflections leave $\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}\times 10\times 2+\binom{10}{2}\times 2 = 320$ elements of $X$ unchanged

> Thus, the total number of different configurations is
> $$\frac{1}{8}(1\times 75900+2\times 0+ 1 \times 132 + 4 \times 320) = 9664$$